# how can i split string data in arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno

im sending string data via serial with following format ex. :45:60 or such as ":120:57".i got the data shown in Serial.println (secondValue) Serial.println (thirdValue); but i cant convert it to int

```
String myString;
char c;
int Index1,Index2,Index3, azi;
String secondValue, thirdValue;
void setup(){
Serial.begin(9600);}
void loop(){
while (Serial.available()>0)
{
delay(10);
c = Serial.read();
 myString += c;
}
 if (myString.length()>0)
{
Index1 = myString.indexOf(':');
Index2 = myString.indexOf(':', Index1+1);
Index3 = myString.indexOf(':', Index2+1);

secondValue = myString.substring(Index1+1, Index2);
thirdValue = myString.substring(Index2+1, Index3);


Serial.println(secondValue);
Serial.println(thirdValue);

myString="";
}
delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Hint: Try String.toInt(), https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial.StringToIntExample

Comment: https://majenko.co.uk/blog/evils-arduino-strings

Comment: https://majenko.co.uk/blog/splitting-text-c

Comment: https://majenko.co.uk/blog/reading-serial-arduino

Answer (score 1):

All numbers are integers?
If yes, you can use `toInt()` function.

```
int secondValueInt, thirdValueInt;

secondValueInt = secondValueInt.toInt();
thirdValueInt = thirdValue.toInt();
```

Comment: thx a lot bro, you are a life saver (Y)